# No endpoint found when deploying a application with a WCF service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I have an MVC3 app with a WCF service reference. Of course when im debugging on my localhost, it runs fine. I published my MVC3 app to my test web server, configured it in IIS and i can get to the home screen fine. I published my WCF app to the same web server, set it up in IIS but when I click my login button which calls a method in my WCF service, i get this error:

```
 [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at 
 http://localhost:56266/RQServices.svc that could accept the message.
```

In IIS i have the site called NewPCloser which points to C:\NewPcloser and in IIS, the WCF app is setup and points to C:\NewPcloser\services. The file RQServices.svc is in this directory. Everything was setup in IIS with all the defaults except where the apps are pointing. I'm not sure what else i need to say or show, but let me know and i'll do it.

My test site is (htp for stackoverflow)htp://devdb/newpcloser. The services are at htp://devdb/newpcloserservices. Should i point something to one of these 2 places?

Bottom line why am I getting this error? Thanks

Comment: Is the URL in the error the correct endpoint address? If so, have you browsed to that address to see if the endpoint is there? Also it looks like you should be looking for http://localhost:56266/services/RQServices.svc - since IIS is pointing to the NewPcloser directory and not the services directory

Comment: It looks like the endpoint you have configured is your Visual Studio debugging session.

Comment: No, thats the endpoint address by default thats setup in VS. My test site is http://devdb/newpcloser. The services are at http://devdb/newpcloserservices. Should i point something to one of these 2 places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `Web.Config` file and see what is the endpoint configuration you have. Make sure it is same as the URL where you get the service.

Assuming your Service is available at this url in your server

```
http://www.yourserver.com/someservice/something.svc
```

then your `endpoint` should look like this

```
<endpoint address="http://www.yourserver.com/someservice/something.svc"  

      other configuration attributes....  />
```

If you hosted it in the same server, you probably would be able to access it with something like `http://localhost/..`  , instead of your domain name in the url

Comment: I added this but i still get the error:       <service name="PaperlessCloser4._0.WCF.RQServices">
        <endpoint binding="ws2007HttpBinding" address="http://devdb/newpcloserservices/RQServices.svc"
          bindingConfiguration="PCActionBinding" contract="PaperlessCloser4._0.WCF.IRQServices" />
      </service>

Comment: what is devdb/newpcloserservices/RQServices.svc ? give a valid url like http:///something/....

Comment: Thats where the WCF services live. I get an error when i type it in a browser. "When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint 'http://devdb/newpcloserservices/RQServices.svc'."